# How to concatenate the first 100 files in a directory?

Tags: linux, cat

I had 4000 text files with unique filenames in a directory.

Is there any **Linux command** to concatenate only the 1-100 files.

```
cat 1.txt ... 100.txt > 1.100.txt
cat 101.txt ... 200.txt > 2.200.txt
.......
.......
cat 3901.txt ... 4000.txt > 40.4000.txt
```

Suggestions please.

Comment: Please properly define "first" and whether the names are truly simply `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt ...`

Comment: or... `cat {1..100}.txt > 1.100.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `head` to only pick 100 files.

For example:

```
cat $(ls -1 --sort=time | head -n 100) > 1.100.txt
```

(you can change the `--sort` to something else or remove it to sort by name)

If spaces or newlines might occur in filenames, you can't use `ls` but `find -print0` is safe (uses null as the separator):

```
find . -type f -print0 | head -z -n 100 | xargs -0 cat > 1.100.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible to do concatenation by providing the filenames in a text file ?

Comment: Sure, replace the `ls -1 |` part with `cat list.txt |`

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
files=( *(N.n) ) i=0
while (( $#files )) {
  () {cat -- $@ > $((++i)).$@[-1]} $files[1,100]
  files[1,100]=()
}
```

The `n` glob qualifier sorts the file names numerically, you can change it to `Om` to `O`rder by `m`odification time from oldest to newest.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to caution you to be careful of using the output of `ls` in any Bash loop as a matter of habit because it can lull you into a false sense of security that it will always work. (Consider what happens with spaces in the filename...) It does work in this case - but there's a better (if somewhat more complicated) way to do it in general if the unique part of the filename is numeric and sequential.

Bash has built-in integer math functionality, and you can use the `seq` command with it to construct a loop to do what you want:

```
i=0
while :; do
    (( i += 1 ))
    (( i >= 4000 )) && break

    files_to_catenate=
    for i in $(seq $i $((i + 99))); do
        files_to_catenate+=( "${i}.txt")
    done
    cat "${files_to_catenate[@]}" > "$((i / 100)).${i}.txt"
done
```

Comment: All the text files has a same prefix OG*********.txt     (Ex. OG0017769.txt)

Comment: Provided the unique portion is numeric and sequential, the above will work. If not, the accepted answer is the only realistic way to do it. Whichever you choose is a matter of preference.

Comment: Bash also has range expansion, but it happens after arithmetic expansion or variable expansion.  So you need `eval echo {$((1 + 2))..9}` to print 3 4 5 ... 9, or `eval cat foo{$i..$((i+99))}.txt >> "foo$i.concat.txt"`, with extra quoting for parts that might contain spaces.  This would be an alternative to your loop.  Perhaps using range-expansion to make an array would be sane.  BTW, with `files=( $(seq --format=%g.txt $i $((i+99)) ) )` you also wouldn't need a loop.

Comment: Be very careful of `eval`. It’s not a bad idea in your particular application, but I wouldn’t make it my first idea when solving a problem. In any case, I try not to build very large arrays (in more than the hundreds of elements) in Bash. It’s not great at large arrays. The cost of a loop is much less than the cost of the disk access here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit creepy but: You could run something along the lines of:

```
for a in {1..40}
do 
  echo cat "{$((a*100-99))..$(($a*100))}.txt > $a.$(($a*100)).txt" 
done
```

echoing

```
cat {1..100}.txt > 1.100.txt
cat {101..200}.txt > 2.200.txt
...
cat {3901..4000}.txt > 40.4000.txt
```

And if you like it: `for a in.....done | bash`